# Xdebug trace Phalcon can not save trace file

Tags: php, xdebug, trace, phalcon

I am using Xdebug to trace PHP. With Laravel project it works well.

php.ini set is like that:

```
zend_extension="/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php/extensions/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable = On
xdebug.auto_trace=1
xdebug.trace_format=0
xdebug.trace_options=1
xdebug.trace_output_dir="/tmp/midi/report/trace/tmp"
xdebug.collect_params=4
xdebug.collect_return=On
xdebug.trace_output_dir=/tmp/midi/trace
```

With `trace_format=0`, `collect_params=4` and `collect_return=On` I can get the trace file named `xxx.xt`

but with the same config my Phalcon project does not work. There is no report generated.

I first consider the Phalcon has problem, but I set the index.php

```
<?php
echo "abcd";
exit;
```

I think this should not use Phalcon because it before use `Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault;` it also no report generated.

What should I do to find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do a phpinfo(); in the index.php to check if xdebug is loaded add at all and what settings are getting into your php config.

Comment: hi, thank you. i diff the laravel and phalcon phpinfo(). find the configure does not work at my phalcon，i write them to php.ini， and i work well。before，they are configure by php -d. next, i will try to find why it not worked.  that is another question,thank you very mush

Comment: hi, i find the reason, before -d configure,i had i router.php. i let the router.php at the last, the question resolve. thank you again

Comment: Ok great that you found the solution.